# How to get additional scopes from GoogleSignIn in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a method which I am using to get a users basic info like birthday, gender & phone number and I'm now sure how to implement it in Flutter?

```
 void signInWithGoogle(context) async {
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      final User user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      
    } catch (error) {
      print('Google error: $error');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

I hope this answer will help you.
You can try adding a scope in your GoogleSignIn() method like that

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);
```

And you can adjust your scopes based on the information you want to access.
And this is the link to the full list of scopes you can use [Google Scopes list](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)

Note that some scopes will require app verification and it's mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Okay. And then what? Which API is accessed to get this information, and how?